# Second fundamental form in almost complex manifold

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $f:\Sigma \to (M,g)$ be an immersed surface in a Riemannian manifold with normal bundle $N$. The second fundamental form $A$ of $f(\Sigma)$ is a section of $S^2(T^*\Sigma)\otimes N$, the bundle of real bilinear symmetric forms with values in $N$.

Suppose that $TM|_{f(\Sigma)}$ admits an almost complex structure (e.g. $M$ is almost complex). Then we can decompose $S^2(T^*\Sigma)\otimes N$ into three parts:
$$
(S^{2,0}(T^*\Sigma)\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} N ) \oplus (S^{1,1}(T^*\Sigma)\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} N ) \oplus (S^{0,2}(T^*\Sigma)\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} N ).
$$
The first summand is complex bilinear, the second is the symmetrization of complex linear in the first argument and antilinear in the second argument. The third summand is anti bilinear.

Under this decomposition, the second fundamental form $A$ splits into three parts. If $J$ is the almost complex structure on $TM|_{f(\Sigma)}$, then
\begin{align}
A^{2,0}(x,y)&=A(x,y)-JA(Jx,y)-JA(x,Jy)-A(Jx,Jy) \\
A^{1,1}(x,y)&=A(x,y)+A(Jx,Jy) \\
A^{0,2}(x,y)&=A(x,y)+JA(Jx,y)+JA(x,Jy)-A(Jx,Jy).
\end{align}

Note that if $e_1,e_2=Je_1$ is an orthonormal basis for $T_p\Sigma$, then $A^{1,1}(e_1,e_1)$ is the mean curvature of $f(\Sigma)$. Thus $A^{1,1}\equiv 0$ iff $f(\Sigma)$ is a minimal surface. Also, the $A^{2,0}$ and $A^{0,2}$ components are conformally invariant.

**Question:** I am interested in what the condition $A^{0,2}\equiv 0$ says about  $f(\Sigma)$. Given $(M,g)$, does there always exist a nonconstant immersion $f:S^2\to M$ with $A^{0,2}\equiv 0$?

Note that any totally umbilic immersion has $A^{0,2}\equiv 0$, as can easily be checked on a basis. Any references would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained your notation, e.g. the upper indices such as $S^{2,0}(\ldots)$.

Comment: Moreover, I believe the second fundamental form is a section of $S^2(T^*\Sigma)\otimes N$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typos.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval: The almost complex structure gives you a decomposition of $2$-tensors into $(p,q)$-types. This works for symmetric tensors as well as for differential forms.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you, I am aware of that. It's just that  I think $\Sigma$ needs a complex structure for that, rather than $TM|_\Sigma$.

Comment: Yes, of course, sorry, @AmitaiYuval. Of course, $\Sigma$ always has a complex structure. The type decomposition, as you point out, is intrinsic to $\Sigma$ and won't depend on the (almost) complex structure of $M$, I guess.